# UIWebView and Gesture Detection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview

HI There,
I have a View Base Project application and one of the viewcotrollers simply manages a view that houses a UIWebView. I need to be able to detect tapping events on the UIWebView. I've tried suggestion here but cannot get it to work. http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/
Would anyone have a sample viewbased application that implements this method. I think Id be able to then use this sample to implement in my own project properly.
Really stuck and wouldn't be asking only I've tried now for 2 days solid to get it to work.
Many thanks for your help on this.
Tony

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it. Should have read article properly. I forgot to Make sure in your MainWindow.xib file, the window is of type TapDetectingWindow and not UIWindow.

Sorry about that.

Tony